# Displaying unicode symbols in HTML

Tags: html, unicode

I want to simply display the tick (✔) and cross (✘) symbols in a HTML page but it shows up as either a box or goop âœ” - obviously something to do with the encoding.

I have set the meta tag to show utf-8 but obviously I'm missing something.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**Edit/Solution:** From comments made, using FireBug I found the headers being passed by my page were in fact "Content-Type: text/html" and not UTF-8. Looking at the file format using Notepad++ showed my file was formatted as "UTF-8 without BOM". Changing this to just UTF-8 the symbols now show correctly... but firebug still seems to indicate the same content-type.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should ensure the HTTP server headers are correct.

In particular, the header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

should be present.

The meta tag is ignored by browsers if the HTTP header is present.

Also ensure that your file is actually encoded as UTF-8 before serving it, check/try the following:

- Ensure your editor save it as UTF-8.
- Ensure your FTP or any file transfer program does not mess with the file.
- Try with HTML encoded entities, like `&#uuu;`.
- To be really sure, hexdump the file and look as the character, for the ✔, it should be E2 9C 94 .

Note: If you use an unicode character for which your system can't find a glyph (no font with that character), your browser should display a question mark or some block like symbol. But if you see multiple roman characters like you do, this denotes an encoding problem.

Comment: Actually, the meta tag is not ignored, but the HTTP header takes precedence. Thanks Konrad for that precision.

Comment: Note that to use a unicode character in the `content` property of a CSS `::before` selector, one would need to use the backslash notation. e.g.: '\2713' instead of '&#2713'.

Answer (score 22):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but wanted to point a few things out.

Setting the `content-type` and `charset` is obviously a good practice, doing it on the server is much better, because it ensures consistency across your application.

However, I would use `UTF-8` only when the language of my application uses a lot of characters that are available only in the `UTF-8` charset. If you want to show a unicode character or symbol in one of cases, you can do so without changing the `charset` of your page.

`HTML` renderers have always been able to display symbols which are not part of the encoding character set of the page, as long as you mention the symbol in its `numeric character reference (NCR)`. Sounds weird but its true.

So, even if your `html` has a header that states it has an encoding of `ansi` or any of the `iso` charsets, you can display a check mark by using its html character reference, in decimal - &#10003; or in hex - &#x2713;

So its a little difficult to understand why you are facing this issue on your pages. Can you check if the NCR value is correct, this is a good reference http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

Comment: "However, I would use UTF-8 only when the language of my application uses a lot of characters that are available only in the UTF-8 charset" Why? What's the disadvantage in switching?

Comment: @dumbledad : Very good question, I guess I let my own bias cloud my answer. What I meant to say was if your entire application is already non utf-8, changing it application vide for a single page might be too much work. Also, if your programming language and content don't need utf-8 characters, you can accidentally copy paste a junk character which your editor will be fine with (since its in utf-8 mode), but the code will fail during execution. Having said that, when you can, update your encoding and char set

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you actually save the file as UTF-8, alternatively use HTML entities (`&#nnn;`) for the special characters.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a HTML entity for ✔ or have I missed it? How do you "actually" save the file as UTF-8 and how can you check?

Comment: @Peter: by using a decent editor. Most text editors have an option in their “save as” dialog to specify the file encoding, or they have another option hidden somewhere in their menu. Vim uses the `fileencoding` setting.

Comment: @Peter, you can refer to any character by its code.  Try &#x2714; for a tick.

Comment: save as utf-8.  interesting concept.  works well if you are creating static HTML pages.  but ... what about dynamic webpages?  this unicode/utf-8/wide character stuff is really quite confusing to me.  my backend code is perl.  the http header is properly set and so is the html header.   W3C Internationalization Checker confirms I have the document set to utf-8.  does CaSinG matter? finally, what about text input boxes?  i still get goop!  :(

Comment: addendum to previous comment: my database shows the data has been entered correctly, and the characters display correctly.  so, not database issue.  my perl script (or rather, the editor) is set to save the scripts as utf-8.  my server, apache2, i am fairly certain is not interfering, or is set right.  all this said, still not sure why chars are goop.  ugh.  there has to be a better way

Answer (score 5):

Unlike proposed by Nicolas, the `meta` tag isn’t actually ignored by the browsers. However, the `Content-Type` HTTP header always has precedence over the presence of a `meta` tag in the document.

So make sure that you either send the correct encoding via the HTTP header, or don’t send this HTTP header at all (not recommended). The `meta` tag is mainly a fallback option for local documents which aren’t sent via HTTP traffic.

Using HTML entities should also be considered a workaround – that’s tiptoeing around the real problem. Configuring the web server properly prevents a lot of nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

A few years late - just to clarify something that was missed out in the answers in case someone is wondering why their unicode encoding still doesn't work.

The uuuu in &#uuuu; is a decimal number: not a hex number.  If you look up the check and cross, you will probably find that sites will say it is 2713 and 2717.  &#2713; will give you ઙ and &#2717; will give you ઝ

Get a hex calculator out and work out the decimal equivalents.

```
2713 hex = 10003 decimal
2717 hex = 10007 decimal
```

Use &#10003; to get ✓ and &#10007; to get ✗

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a file problem, you simple saved your file in 1-byte encoding like latin-1. Google up your editor and how to set files to utf-8.

I wonder why there are editors that don't default to utf-8.