# jquery arabic letters support

Tags: jquery, arabic, letters

This code works very well:

Html

```
<html><body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body></html>
```

Jquery

```
$('<div id="footer"><p>جميع الحقوق محفوظه لشركة</p></div>').insertAfter('#container');
```

but the problem in Arabic letters its look like that:

```
������������������������
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying unicode symbols in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html)

Comment: This is a character set issue: You need to get your encodings right. Good basic reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 4):

You should probably specify an encoding on your page to get around issues like this. Here's a page from the W3C on specifying character encodings:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2

You should be fine with UTF-8, which you can specify by putting the following tag in your `<head>` tag:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Right, the people who've commented on your answer are absolutely correct, too. :)

Comment: tried all above this is this the result
افرئٍسٍةافإشترا�اتصف بلااف�رنغ

Answer (score 0):

Try using escape():

```
$('<div id="footer"><p>'+escape('جميع الحقوق محفوظه لشركة')+'</p></div>').insertAfter('#container');
```