# How To Show Icon In TreeView Node Using 2 Strings?

Tags: c#, treeview

If I have a TreeView with the font to Segoa UI Emoji. I need to set a TreeView node icon using 2 strings but doesn't work. Also, what value can I use for the `unicodeEndStr` variable below if the unicode only has 4 digits like `2639` ?

```
// This code shows emoji icon in treeview node followed by a space and some text
string emoji = "\U0001F608" + " " + "Face Savoring Food";
EmojiTreeView.Nodes.Add(emoji);

// This code does not show emoji icon, just \U0001F608 followed by a space and some text
string unicodeStartStr = "\\U000"; // need double back slashes to compile
string unicodeEndStr = "1F608";
string emojiCodeStr = unicodeStartStr + unicodeEndStr;
string emojiStr = emojiCodeStr + " " + "Face Savoring Food";
EmojiTreeView.Nodes.Add(emojiStr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse your combined Unicode string as hex(16-bit) number.
Then use char.ConverFromUtf32(str).ToString() to generate complete Unicode symbol.

Reference solution: [Dynamic generate 8-Digit-Unicode to Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990022/dynamic-generate-8-digit-unicode-to-character)

```
public Form1()
{
           InitializeComponent();
           treeView1.Nodes.Add("\U0001F608" + " " + "Face Savoring Food");

           // remove \u prefix
           string unicodeStartStr = "000";  
           string unicodeEndStr = "1F608";
           string emojiCodeStr = unicodeStartStr + unicodeEndStr;
           int value = int.Parse(emojiCodeStr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
           string result = char.ConvertFromUtf32(value).ToString();
           string emojiStr = result + " " + "Face Savoring Food";
           treeView1.Nodes.Add(emojiStr);
}
```

[Worked result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaMnS.png)

Comment: Fantastic Li, works perfectly. But what if `string unicodeEndStr = "2639";` ?

Comment: @GRF , it also works with only `string unicodeEndStr = "2639";` to show white frowning face emoji. It's still parsed as correct hex number.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Just tried it. Works GREAT. You don't happen to know of a Color Font for Windows 7 that I could set the TreeView control to instead of B/W Segoa UI Emoji ?