# PHP preg_replace for multi language

Tags: php

I have input search use `preg_replace`, however I wish my search input accept others language

**Keep** - Chinese, Japaneses, German.. etc.

**Remove** - symbol character like @#$%^*() those

This one only keep english   `preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $search);`

any way to set up for multi language?

Comment: So, what *do* you want to keep and what do you want to remove? May it be easier to use a blacklist rather than a whitelist?

Comment: To regex/php, `æ` is as much of a unicode character as `^`. Your best bet it to make a blacklist, and simply replace with that. (`preg_replace("/[!\"#¤%&\(\)=/]+", "", $search);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [PHP unicode regex reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). The plus `+` isn't necessary as PHP will loop through the string. The `\s` will match all whitespace characters.

```
preg_replace("![^\p{L}\p{N}\s]!", "", $search);
```

If you want to match only the space character itself you would add it in the brackets as a literal:

```
preg_replace("![^\p{L}\p{N} ]!", "", $search);
```

**Update** Added bit about spaces per comment request

Comment: how to keep space? " "

Comment: I've added the whitespace character match `\s`.

Comment: one more question, when I out put, it become symbol

Comment: That has to do with the encodings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html

Answer (score 3):

Though for java, a concise overview [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

You can use the so called Posix notation:

```
[^\p{Alnum}\p{M}]
```

The first is the alphanumeric group, and the second the combining diacritical marks: the accents.
The latter should not be forgotten because one can write `ĉ` as one Unicode point c-circumflex, but also as 'c' followed by a combining circumflex `^` (zero width, here represented by the normal circumflex). In some languages there are more than one marks to a base letter.

---

Correction:

```
[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]
```

Comment: The php reference for the same: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: What to do for this 
if i need to do @Hello
I want this for use mention feature

Comment: @SandipJha I am unsure what you want. As also this question is closed, just ask a question yourself.