# Unable to display unicode characters on HTML5 page

Tags: html, unicode

I am using a virtual keyboard on my HTML5 page that has certain unicode characters like tick (✔) and cross (✘). I am not able to display them on my page.

I followed [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html) and added `<meta charset="UTF-8">` before/within the `<head>` tag but I am still getting the characters as a square box on the virtual keyboard.

Any clues where am I going wrong?

Thanks guys.

P.S: I am using Verdana font and that is as per client requirements.

Comment: Is your file encoded in UTF-8 ? Served as UTF-8 ?

Comment: *"before/after"* ? What do you mean ? Can you show the relevant part of your code ?

Comment: A "square box" typically means that the font you're using on the page does not contain that character and/or that the browser cannot resolve and visual *glyph* in any font for the character.

Comment: Hi dystroy, I meant to say that I tried adding the meta tag just before the <head> tag and also within the <head> but they didn't help me any way

Comment: Hi deceze, my page uses Verdana. And I am afraid I don't know how to check whether it supports these characters or not :(

Comment: I use [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/software/babelmap.html) to check font coverage (among other things). There may be other more specialised tools though.

Answer (score 2):

you should check if the font you're using on that page contain those characters.

Comment: Wasil, I'm using Verdana. But how am I supposed to check whether that has got these characters or not?