# HTML Mandarin isnt working

Tags: html

Ive been making a website for a technology fair project, and it has come to a stage where I want to make it more universal. However when I try to add another language (Chines Mandarin as an example) It just converts the text to some wired english characters.

Here is my example Website

```
<html lang="cmn">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- This is meant to say in Mandarin "This is some text" -->
    這是一些文本
</body>
</html>
```

But when the page loads, this is what I get

```
 é€™æ˜¯ä¸€äº›æ–‡æœ¬
```

Im pretty sure that its not some settings in my browser Firefox, because I've or so tried it in Google Chrome

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying unicode symbols in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following `meta` definition inside your `head` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

?