# Unable to display Chinese characters, shows giberish

Tags: windows, tomcat, browser

Basically, I've tried with 5 pcs, and 4 of them can display the character properly. And i need to use this 1 pc that CANNOT display the characters. I've checked the local settings for all of them and its the same. So i guess its not a pc thing. I've tried using different browsers and checking the browser settings too.

Oddly, this pc can view other chinese websites with no problem,  but when i run my own server and connect, it doesnt show the chinese character properly.

info: I'm using Tomcat 7, but since all the other pc is showing i dont think its tomcat's problem. Also, the data in the database ,which the server calls from, is fine, but when the data is returned to the browser, it is giberish.

Edit: the problem is not that the server does not work at all. its that it works with some but not with this particular device.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-put-mandarin-chinese-on-a-website/2945/2  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Mandarin isnt working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909632/html-mandarin-isnt-working)

Comment: @Hack-R I dont think its the same as these two because the chinese characters are readable with other devices, just now this particular one.

Comment: Other devices? Please provide a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This is to do with your HTML, not Tomcat.

Comment: I would suggest adding the command line arguments -Duser.language=zh -Duser.country=CN or similar in your tomcat's startup.bat/sh script. My guess would be that on the PC it doesn't work on it's picking up the wrong country or language.