# Unicode html buffers not working with libmicrohttpd

Tags: html, c, http, unicode, server

I am trying to create a server which will server pages in non English language, and i am testing libmicrohttpd with this code:

```
static int
answer_to_connection(void* cls, struct MHD_Connection* connection,
                     const char* url, const char* method,
                     const char* version, const char* upload_data,
                     size_t* upload_data_size, void** con_cls)
{
    char *page = "<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>हैलो यूनिकोड</body></html>";


    struct MHD_Response* response;
    int ret;

    response =
        MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(page), (void *)page,
                                        MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);

    ret = MHD_queue_response(connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);
    MHD_destroy_response(response);

    return ret;
}
```

But its not working and giving ????? characters on the browser.
Can anyone tell me if libmicrohttpd supports Unicode, if yes then how?

Comment: i did that but no luck.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html. Be sure your string is formatted in UTF-8. If you're using a C11 compiler prefix string with `u8` as: `char *page = u8"<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>हैलो यूनिकोड</body></html>";`

Comment: yea that worked!!!! thank you, add this as an answer, i will mark as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already wrote in the comment you have to be sure that your string is formatted in UTF-8. Standard `char` type formats string as per the selected codepage or local, that gives bad formed characters if interpreted as UTF-8.

If you're using a C11 compiler prefix string with `u8` as:

```
char *page = u8"<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>हैलो यूनिकोड</body></html>";
```

If your compiler doesn't support UTF-8 you need an external tool that formats the string using hex escaping or octal or the like.