# Extended characters not displaying C#

Tags: c#, unicode, web-applications, extended-ascii

I am currently working on a web application using C#.

One of the online forms allows the user to update their address.

However, when I enter for example : ÀîâãäåæéêìñóôõăąăĂąĄ into any of the address info

and then search for the same user again their address is displayed on the screen [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O2c0.png).

As you can see the last characters seem to be wrong.

Wrong in the database too.

Do I need to do something to the string before I send it for update, at the moment I just convert whatever is in the text field to uppercase and send the information to my stored procedure.

```
,@p_AddressLine1 char(40)=NULL
,@p_AddressLine2 char(40)=NULL
,@p_AddressLine3 char(40)=NULL
,@p_AddressLine4 char(40)=NULL
,@p_AddressLine5 char(40)=NULL
```

Please help. Note Ive tried changing to nchar - but I think this may be a C# thing?
Thanks

```
user.PostCode = this.tbPostCode1.Text.ToUpper().Trim() + " " + this.tbPostCode2.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
        user.AddressLine1 = this.txtAddressLine1.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
        user.AddressLine2 = this.txtAddressLine2.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
        user.AddressLine3 = this.txtAddressLine3.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
        user.AddressLine4 = this.txtAddressLine4.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
        user.AddressLine5 = this.txtAddressLine5.Text.ToUpper().Trim();



        user.Update(user);
```

Comment: What is your database default collation? e.g. `select serverproperty('collation')`

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: When you use the debugger before presenting the info on a web page, is the value still wrong? Also, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html)

Comment: Yes the value is still wrong just before display.

Comment: Is it corrupted before your stored procedure is called?

Comment: No I can see in the debugger the format is just changed to upper text but not corrupt

Comment: You mentioned you tried changing to `nchar`, did you change the parameter type and the field type in the table too? You would also need to re-run the update though, since `char` does not really support Unicode by design you cannot store characters like these in it.

Comment: The field type goes to the DB as "String", just changed the parameter type...not the field type in the table

Comment: And what is the field type in the table? If the string is correct before calling the sp you might be trying to squeeze Unicode characters to `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with extended character set which cannot be stored in `char` field type and you can only use `nchar` or `nvarchar` for that, but be aware about the space requirement for the Unicode characters which will take as twice as more space.

Here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server) explaining the difference and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) is the documentation on the data types you should be using instead.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked a treat!!!!! 
Still coming through in CSV wrong though - comes through as:
&#192;&#206;&#194;&#195;&#196;&#197;&#198;&#201;&#202;&#204;&#209;&#211;&#212;&#213;Ä‚Ä„Ä‚Ä‚Ä„Ä„

Comment: This time it looks more like Unicode character encoded as HTML Entity