# In Rails - is there a rails view helper to deal with tabs ("\t")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, format

I have a bunch of text in db that has tabs chars (`\t`'s) in it.  I want it rendered it on the web page as intended by the author.  What's the right way to do that?

In other words, I'm looking for tabs analog of `simple_format`.

Doing `<%= text.gsub("\t", "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp") %>` to achieve that doesn't seem right somehow.  There has to be a more elegant railsy way.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2665582/4414956 ?

Comment: You could use `<%= text.gsub("\t", "&emsp;") %>` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Spaces_in_Unicode