# How to insert tab in a jsf page?

Tags: jsf, tabs

How do I insert a tab in a jsf page?

```
<h:outputText class="text" value="#{BackingBean.line1}" />
```

This doesn't work:

```
String line1 = "Scale \t: " + vss.getScale();
```

Any idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-nbsp

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace is in HTML by default not accounted as part of presentation. You'd need to use HTML elements like `<br/>` for a newline or `<ul><li>` for lists or `<dl><dt><dd>` for definitions. Most likely the `<dl><dt><dd>` is most suitable for you.

If you have a hard head in, you could always just set the CSS `white-space` property of the parent element to `pre`.

E.g.

```html
<h:outputText ... styleClass="preformatted" />
```

*(please note that the `class` attribtue is invalid. It should be `styleClass`)*

with

```css
.preformatted {
    white-space: pre;
}
```