# Formatting HTML list to add variable size space

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to put a "tab" symbol inside a list, so different length words will be formatted like a table:

For example

```
<li>Word1 <something> description111111111111</li>
<li>Word2222222 <something> description</li>
```

At the end it would look like this:

```
Word1            description11111111111
Word2222222      description
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Unless it is tabular data, don't use tables. Also, what are your browser support requirements? Also, looks like a definitions list (`<dl>`) might work better for you

Comment: It is just an example. Actually I generate list with AJAX so it changes on time and values are also different :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SPAN tag, then position it absolute within the LI tag:

```
 <li>Column 1<span>Column 2</span></li>
```

CSS

```
li { position: relative } 
li span { position: absolute; left: 100px }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571662/96505) which says:

> It's much cleaner to use CSS. Try padding-left:5em or margin-left:5em as appropriate instead.