# adding space in texbox results when sending thru email

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

wassup guys im new to C# coding and i did a search but couldn't find exactly what im looking for. So i have a couple of text-boxes which holds string elements and integers

what i want to do is when these boxes are filled in i want to send a summary of the email to client/customer but the format is whats getting me.

(first, one) are strings equaling different text-boxes

my code is:

```
emailCompseTask.Body = first + one + Enviroment.NewLine +
                       second + two + Enviroment.NewLine
```

and so on problem is which i send thru email it shows something like this:

```
computer service25.00
```

instead of:

```
computer service      25.00
```

is there a way to add spacing to make this more presentable? or even a better way perhaps thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused, but you just want to add some spacing in the output?  Just throw some spaces in there like you would another variable.

```
    first + " " + one + Environment.NewLine
    + second + " " + two + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: ahhhh this worked also! i thought i tried this lol i dont think i added the plus sign afterwards thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
emailCompseTask.Body = first + one + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ second + two ;
```

body takes as `HTML` input, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-nbsp) for more spacing option.

Comment: actually when i did this the output came out exactly how you have it written

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table

```
        string tableRow = @"<tr>
                       <td>{0}</td>
                       <td>{1}</td>
                    </tr>";

        string htmlTable = @"<table>
                             {0}
                            </table>";

        string rows = "";

        // Can do this in a loop 
        rows += string.Format(tableRow, first, one);
        rows += string.Format(tableRow, first, one);

        emailComseTask.Body = string.Format(htmlTable, rows);
```

Comment: nice never used a table before but its something new thanks alot!