# HTML create shorthand for multiple spaces

Tags: html

I have to write documentation for a program in classis HTML (no CSS/XML etc.).
The problem appears when I have to enter multiple spaces/tabs in the document.

Since there is no "tab" in HTML, so I am using 4 non-breakable spaces as a tab character. However, when I need 2 tabs, it becomes too repetitive to enter `&nbsp;`  8 times.

Is there any possibility to create/define a custom shorthand/shortcut notation for this, e.g. instead of entering `&nbsp;`  8 times, I can use `&_8nbsp;` to create 8 inline spaces ?

Comment: What about using &emsp;

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-nbsp

Answer (score 3):

**Here are some types of ways to add spaces:**

Use `&nbsp;` to add a single space

Use `&ensp;` to add 2 spaces

Use `&emsp;` to add 4 spaces

Use `&nbsp;` 4 times to insert a tab

*I hope this one is helpful!*

Answer (score 1):

To respect whitespace in HTML, you can use `PRE` element or equivalent CSS ([`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)).

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut in HTML to create multiple whitespaces. You should probably put the information in different tags and style them with CSS according to your specification.