# R shiny tab symbol \t in h4()

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display some text with R shiny:

```
 h4("Hello world!   \t \t   Hier I'm)
```

How can I add tab symbols into the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pre` tag preserves spaces and line breaks; and escaped characters like `\t` are interpreted. For example : `tags$pre(h4("Hello world!   \t \t   Hier I'm))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really directly enter a tab character like you can in R. You can insert consecutive `&nbsp;` values for spaces - this example puts 4 spaces into the space that you have above:

`h4("Hello world!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hier I'm)`

Alternatively you can add padding or margin to your CSS for `h4` tags. See this link for explanation:

[HTML: Tab space instead of multiple non-breaking spaces ("nbsp")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-nbsp)