# how to print data in a datatable such that every row of comes in a new line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datatables

I have written code to display the data in table.. but they are coming together when I display and it looks like mess. The newline character '\n' is not working here.. It will give only one space gap.. I am using visual studio 2008 for coding and using c# for programming. Please have a look at my page and tell what new line character I need to use.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTablesell.Rows)
            {
                Response.Write(row["scriptname"].ToString()); 
                Response.Write(row["accnum"].ToString());
                Response.Write(row["Quantity"].ToString());
                Response.Write(row["price"].ToString());
                Response.Write("\n");

            }
```

The Output of this will come as ----> script4201025 script4151050
But I need every row to come in new line In the first line "scrpt4 20 10 25" and in second line "script4 15 10 50"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
Response.Write("\n");
```

use break tag

```
Response.Write("<br/>");
```

for Break tag

Comment: Do you know how to leave a tab space as we use "\t" in C??

Comment: @Darkknight you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-non-breaking-spaces-nbsp

Comment: thank u @Ganesh_Devalekar... Ganesh Chaturti ka shubhkamanaye :)

Comment: @Darkknight :) same to you