# \t not working in text body of a mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application where I create contents of an email. In the text body I am using `\t` but the effect cannot be seen in the mail. Whereas `\n` is appearing in the mail content. How can I put `\t`?

Comment: Please include your code and the generated email content.

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-non-breaking-spaces-nbsp

Answer (score 1):

You should use [line break](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) element.

Depending on html templating engine you use:

```
# in haml
%br
# in erb
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks :) This works ! But I also need spaces ( tab ) between text.

Comment: @user2851669  what tab between which parts of text? line break should solve the issue with new line

Comment: text = ["This is how \t should be"]                                                               Expected output = This is how .......... should be,  where . is a blank space

Comment: @user2851669 still do not understand fully what you need. But I recommend you to check html tags to see, what you need. `<p>`and so on..

Comment: &nbsp; solved the problem for now, it's not a nice fix though

Comment: edit your question with the code of the mailer please