# Insert blank space between two words in html

Tags: javascript, html

I wan to insert some spaces in between two words and I do not want to use `pre` tags. In my code here is one input field where user can enter text and some javascript code display it in `div` you can check the code right below.

```
<input type="text" id="user-input" />

<div id="user-text"></div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
    $(document).on('keyup', '#user-input', function(event){
var userText = $('#user-text');
var clientText = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
if(event.keyCode === 32 || event.which === 32){ clientText += '&nbsp;';  }
    clientText = $('<textarea />').html(clientText).text();

    userText.text(clientText);
});
```

I'm using `&nbsp;` for inserting space between two words but this is not working. It only insert one space if I want to insert ten space then what.
The code is not working like as I'm expecting you can't able to insert more than one space using this code.

**UPDATE**
I want like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** insert more than one `&nbsp;` to text and it will be displayed correctly. Simple white-spaces are truncated to single.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').on('input change', function () {
    $('#span1').html(
      $(this).val() + '&nbsp;'.repeat($(this).val().length)
    );
    $('#span2').html(
      $(this).val() + ' '.repeat($(this).val().length)
    );
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Some text"/><br/>
<span id='span1'>Some text</span>Other text to pad with <b>&amp;nbsp;</b>.<br/>
<span id='span2'>Some text</span>Other text to pad with <b>white-space</b>.
```

---

To preserve user entered white spaces:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('input change', function() {
    $('span').html(
        $(this).val().toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;')
    );
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
<br/>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Please see the update. Your code is not generating same result

Comment: @AzeemHaider You want to preserve user entered white spaces? If so, check edit

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to insert say 10 spaces, then you have to **put &nbsp 10 times**.

```
clientText += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

You can learn more about HTML entities related to spaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-non-breaking-spaces-nbsp).

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace() just replace all the \s equivalent space to nbsp;

```
var userText = $('#user-text');
$(document).on('input', '#user-input', function(event){
    userText.html( $(this).val().replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;') );
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7010/)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple convertSpace function to take care of converting blank spaces to nbsp. https://jsfiddle.net/elemilion/6own3g7z/

```
function convertSpacesToNbsp(str){
return str.split('').map(function(char){
if(char === ' '){
    char = '&nbsp;';
}
return char;
}).join('');
}
$(document).on('keyup', '#user-input', function(event){
var userText = $('#user-text');
var inputStr = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
var clientText = convertSpacesToNbsp(inputStr);
userText.html(clientText);
});
```