# Best way add newline and tab to html and javascript being stored in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, format

I have a `data.json` file that contains `html`, `css` and `js` which I am then using to display it on a webpage.

An example of the `data.json` file is this

```js
{
  {
    "content": "Variables",
    "id": "#variables",
    "html": "<html>\n\t<p>Variables</p>\n</html>",
    "js": "var message = 'Hello World';\nvar name = 'Peter';
  }
}
```

You can see that I am using `\n` for a newline and `\t` for a tab indentation. This is because it is in a json file so I cannot have tabs and newlines (as far as I am aware). This works, however, it is quite time consuming. It would be far more convenient to write the code in my text editor and then pass through some online tool which would do this formatting for me.

Does anyone know of such a tool or a way I could do this easily?

Comment: A json solution which helped me in same situation was https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify

Comment: @VinodLouis does this actually insert the `\n` and `\t` into my code though, or will it just remove it?

Comment: it will convert into tab and new line in visual

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that easier to use HTML + CSS classes within your "html" property in JSON file?

Look at this, much cleaner solution (padding or margin):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571662/3915319

Comment: thanks for your help, but it isnt quite that straight forward unfortunately