# Process clipboard data from Google Sheets, Excel or HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm looking for the functionality to process data from Google Sheets, Excel and plain HTML tables.

I'm using [clipboard data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) on paste event to get the contents of clipboard.

`var clipText = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');`

Though I not quite sure how to process the data and which symbols are used to delimit the rows and the columns. Ideally I would like to have an array of rows with array of columns.

`Holidays taken in the last six months
ID  Name    July    August  September   October November    December
215 Abel    5   2   0   0   0   3
231 Annette 0   5   3   0   0   6
173 Bernard 2   0   0   5   0   0
141 Gerald  0   10  0   0   0   8
99  Michael 8   8   8   8   0   4`

So e.g. a plain copy from HTML is results in this format, some cells are delimited with 3 spaces and some with 2 (Gerald 10 -> 0)

My desired result:

```
[
   [ID, Name, July, August, September, October, November, December],
   [215, Abel, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
   [231, Annette, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3]
    ...
]
```

Are there any special characters that can be used to break / delimit the tabular data from clipboard?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128811/2889347

Comment: Did you get a solution to this @Runnick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delimit by two or more spaces in a row, you can use a regular expression to do it:

```
const clipText = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
const splitByLines = clipText.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/g, clipText)  // Split lines for Windows (\r\n) or Linux/OSX (\n).  See note below...
const splitBySpaces = splitByLines.forEach(line => line.split(/\s{2,}/g))  // Split each line everywhere there are 2 or more spaces in a row
```

If you want to support Unicode input or some really obscure systems, you should take a look at what ECMA considers an 'end-of-line' character: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-line-terminators